# Feedback system only allow 1 per user

Tags: php, mysql

I am implementing a feedback system on a website, but a user should only be allowed to give feedback to another user once.

The only way i can think of doing it would be create another database that shows who has left who feedback by tracking id's, but im sure there is a simpler way to achieve the same result im just not seeing it? Or would the initial way i planned it by putting the information into another database be the best solution?

The code i have so far is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['good'])) {

        $thumbsUp = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET good_feedback = '". $newGood1 ."' WHERE `username` = '". $profileUser ."'");

    if($thumbsUp) {
            echo 'You have left feedback';
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['bad'])) {

        $thumbsUp = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET bad_feedback = '". $newGood2 ."' WHERE `username` = '". $profileUser ."'");

    if($thumbsDown) {
        echo 'You have left bad feedback';
        }
    }

    if (logged_in() == true && $user_data['username'] != $profile_data['username']) {
        echo '<p style="font-size: 17px; margin-left: 22%;">Leave Feedback: </p>';
        echo '<form method="post" style="margin-left: 8%;">
            <button class="btn-u" name="good">Good Feedback</button>
            <button class="btn-u" name="bad">Bad Feedback</button>
            </form>';

    } else {
        echo 'you cannot leave feedback for yourself!';
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

PLEASE NOTE: I KNOW THE ABOVE CODE IS OPEN TO SQL INJECTION'S

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up an environment with the constraint that "A" can only give feedback to "B" once, then you can do so with a unique index.  Here is a very simplified form of what you can do:

```
create table feedback (
    FromUser int,
    ToUser int,
    Message varchar(255)
);

create unique index idx_feedback_from_to on feedback(fromuser, touser);
```